# Adding +1 to query to get around "division by zero" errors

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following "users" table:

```
uid  followers  following  ff_fraction
--------------------------------------
1    40         2          20
2    10         3           3
3     0         2           0
4     5         0           5
5    77         2
6     9         3
```

I want to calculate, for each user, the fraction of followers/following, rounded to a whole number. I filled in the table for the first 4 users:

1. 40/2 = 20
2. 10/3 = 3.3333 => rounded 3
3. 0/2  = 0
4. 5/0 => this would give an error, so I counted +1, making 5/1 = 5

I now have the following query, but it does not account for "following" being zero (and that it thus would have to add 1 in order to not get a devision by zero error):

```
UPDATE users SET ff_fraction = ROUND(followers/following)
```

Is it possible to solve this in a MySQL query?

Comment: If your main aim is to avoid divide by zero error, you should rather add 1 in both numerator and denominator. This is called Laplace Smoothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
UPDATE users SET ff_fraction = ROUND(followers/if(following>0,following,1))
```

Comment: Although this function does the trick, I find this situation easier to deal with using GREATEST due to less numbers and variables.

Comment: @reveller, Robin is right, and depending on your desired outcome, and if you're using signed integers or not, this may influence your answer. If your column is always positive, then the above will work. You may even want to profile both queries to ensure best performance. If you need to take into account negative values then look at safarov and guffa's answers too

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE users SET ff_fraction = ROUND(followers / GREATEST(following, 1))
```

[GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) will make so this never drops below 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression to circumvent the division altogether:

```
update users
set ff_fraction =
  case following when 0 then followers else round(followers/following) end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users 
SET ff_fraction = if(following = 0, followers, ROUND(followers/following))
```